# Why do I have to say "lights outlet" instead of "lights" *sometimes* when telling Siri to turn on/off the lights?

Tags: siri, homekit

There are periods of time (like a week or two) that happens maybe every 1-3 months where when I ask Siri to turn on or off a device plugged into an outlet, I have to use the word "outlet" when I specify the device's name, e.g. "Turn on the lights outlet".  If I don't specify "outlet", Siri says "Sorry, I wasn't able to find anything like that this time".  The rest of the time, "Turn on the lights" is sufficient.

I'm looking for a technical explanation, because I'm using Siri with HAP-Node.js via both/either Homebridge or Node Red.  I'm not interested in answers saying its unsupported.  However, I would be interested to hear in the comments if anyone has ever encountered this issue using a supported homekit setup.

The consensus on the [homebridge github issue](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/issues/2165) is that this is a bug in Apple's software, but no one can explain it.  The evidence that it's an issue with apple is that some iOS devices experience the issue while others do not.  There are temporary solutions that work, such as renaming the device or going through some config removal, etc., but the issue recurs.

Comment: Maybe the "via both" is the clue?  Try disabling one and test and then disable that and enable the other and see if there is a difference.

Comment: I only recently set up node red to do that and in fact, a big part of the reason I set up node red’s HomeKit nodes was to debug and/or work around this recurring issue, so it can’t be that.

Comment: And you have exactly the same issue with just node red?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Yes, I get that erroneous response when telling Siri about a device configured in node red. But if you mean “without an instance of homebridge running alongside node red”, no. However, each system has its own set of independent device configurations, though they are the same physical devices. The only fully independent case I can cite is that I was having this issue before ever installing node red.